# Completely new to Programming, want to learn ActionScript 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3

I am entirely new to learning programming, and my father recommended this site to me. I wanted to learn Actionscript 3.0 to possibly make my own flash game. There is alot of things I need help on because I am completely clueless. What kind of things should I download, do I have to pay for any of this?(I don't have money to spend, sadly.) Where can I find some good tutorials? Do I need any kind of client to play around with actionscript 3.0 and learn the language? Sorry if some of these questions don't really make sense, like I said, entirely new to the programming world, but I really want to make my own MMORPG,(completely unrealistic dream), and I want to start small, try making money off flash games, get some programming experience, any help anyone can provide would be great. All I ask is please do not tell me how unrealistic my dream of making an MMORPG is, just mentioned it to give a little insight as to why I wanted to learn programming. I know it's crazy, but that's why it's a dream, a goal I'm hoping to achieve one day.

Comment: Great Goal. Programming ROCKS!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I highly recommend downloading [Flash Develop](http://www.flashdevelop.org/wikidocs/index.php?title=Main_Page) (requires windows) for development, its a free, and also IMO the best, AS3 editor. It'll get you up and running. If you are on a mac you might want to start with free trials of the Adobe code editors.

For resources & tutorials, the web is full of free stuff to get you started. A couple are [8bitrocket](http://www.8bitrocket.com/) & [gamedev.stackexchange](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) The first thing to do is just pick a simple game (perhaps a true/false trivia game) And just build it. For getting started with general AS3 programming look [here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript.html) for a variety of docs & tutorials.

Good luck, and have fun!

Answer (score 2):

Flex is a free product made by Adobe itself, and uses ActionScript 3.

Here's a link to a game dev site with tutorials on how to make a game for free using flex:

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/92205-making-flash-games-for-the-non-flash-developer-part-i/
http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/92293-making-flash-games-for-the-non-flash-developer-part-ii/
http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/92746-making-flash-games-for-the-non-flash-developer-part-iii/
http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/92893-making-flash-games-for-the-non-flash-developer-part-iv/

If you read through the link article carefully, you can use eclipse (free) with a flex plugin, instead of having to use the flex builder.